# something that looks like a Renewal Process, but it is not

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Assume $X_{n}$ is an i.i.d (independent, identical distribution) sequence of random variables with the distribution function F(x) and non-negative expected value, $EX_{n}=\mu>0$ . Let $Y_n=0,Y_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k, n>=1; N(t)=sup[n:Y_n<=t]$. Find the distribution of N(t) and EN(t).

Now if $X_{n}$s were non-negative, $N_t$ would be a renewal process. but, here, the only info we have (that I don't know where to use it) is that $EX_{n}=\mu>0$.
so my first question is

1-N(t) is a counting process anyway, regardless of $X_n$ being positive or negative, right? what is its distribution function?

2-I have read this almost related answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654305/renewal-process-and-renewal-function
but as I said I'm not sure if it is a renewal process at all. If yes, I am not sure if the lower limit of the integral $(F \star F)(t)=\int_0^t F(t-u)F(du)$ should stay $0$ or it should be - infinity?

3- Is the following way to compute $EN(t)=m_t$ correct? 
$m_t=\sum_{n=0}^{\inf}nP(N(T)=n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\inf}P(N(T)>=n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\inf}P(Y_n<=t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\inf}F_n(t)$ where $F_n(t)$ is the dirstibution function of $Y_n$

Comment: No, this is not a counting process (1.-2.), rather, $N(t)$ is the last visit of the process $(Y_n)$ in the set $(-\infty,t]$. No, $P(N(t)\geqslant n)$ is not $P(Y_n\leqslant t)$ in general (3.) since $[N(t)\geqslant n]=\bigcup\limits_{k=n}^\infty[Y_k\leqslant t]$, not $[Y_n\leqslant t]$. Computing the distribution of $N(t)$ seems like a daunting task (if possible at all), are you sure you were not given some further hypotheses on the distribution of the increments $X_k$?

Comment: @Did No, no further information is given. Just the one I've mentioned up there. How can I use the non-negativeness of the expected value? Why is it given at all? I can't find any useful information from it. What is non-negativeness of a series of RVs tells us anyway? The distribution of most of the RVs are non-negative?!

Comment: That $\mu>0$ ensures that $N(t)$ is almost surely finite. As I said, not much more can be said in the general case (and I fail to understand the two last questions in your comment).

Comment: @Did Thanks. Don't worry about them. I asked them wrong.